# ¿Cómo puedo agregar funcionalidad a un elemento HTML generado dinámicamente?

Tags: nodejs, patrones-de-diseño, buenas-prácticas

Tengo el siguiente módulo que exporta una clase :

```
export class formProduct {

    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.productView = new productView(this.data);
    }
   
    render() {
        productView.productsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", this.productView.card);
    }
}
```

Y en el index lo importo y lo uso al recibir los datos de una API:

```
    dataFromApi.forEach((productData) =>{
      let product = new formProduct(productData)
      product.render()
    })
```

Ésto inyecta unas tarjetas con el siguiente formato en el HTML:

```
    <div>
        <div>
            <p id="id-description">Lorem ipsum....</p>
            <button id="id-edit-btn"></button>
            <button id="id-delete-btn"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ahora, ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de enviar un comportamiento a los 2 botones que se generan dinámicamente? Ésto teniendo en cuenta que estoy haciendolo con vanilla javascript.
Intenté creando un método en el "controlador" que recibiera una función y se la inyectara al elemento "id-edit-btn" y al "id-delete-btn". Pero el comportamiento que necesito pasarle es un método de un objeto creado con otra clase. Siempre me hago lio con éstos casos. ¿Debería tener en cuenta algún patrón de diseño?
Gracias por los aportes.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask]. Es probable que esta pregunta sea respondida con opiniones más que con hechos y citas. Debe ser actualizada para que conduzca a respuestas basadas en hechos.

Comment: No preguntes por "la mejor manera" de hacer algo, ya que las preguntas muy amplias y basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). No fomentes el debate, ya que [es.so] _no es un foro de discusión_ (y esto es lo primero que se menciona en el [tour]).

Comment: El problema se reduce a ¿Cómo identificar al elemento contenedor?, lo obvio es con su `id` asignado desde el constructor.

Comment: En el pseudocódigo no lo incluí, pero en la clase que crea la vista lo tiene. El tema es que cada tarjeta tiene un botón que cuando se dispara el click, manda los datos al formulario. Si yo llamo a otra función ya fuera del forEach que hago de las respuestas de la api, se haría mas largo el código porque tengo que guardar en algún lado todos esos datos de los productos para después retomarlos dentro de la función que ejecuta el click para cada boton. Quería incluir el funcionamiento del boton en el mismo bloque lo crea, con los datos de la API.